# check if the path string given is invalid

Tags: c#, file-io, uri, filepath

I have here a textbox that should accept a file path. How should I validate (by a button click) whether the given path file do exists or not?

For example, "C:MyDocs\sample.txt" should be invalid because it is not actually existing in my local drive and there's no '\' after 'C:'..

i have tried using this:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fName);
 if (fi.Exists)
    //do something
```

but it doesn't satisfy my issue..can anyone advise?

Comment: `fi.Exists` would evaluate to false , so what doesn't actually work ?

Comment: you need to highlight your issue coz if aspnet, how would you be able to map a file which is valid on the client machine and not on your server where you do these checks ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(path, UriKind.Absolute);` to check if the path is valid (beside if the file exists)

read here for Uri validation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Sample:

```
bool isValid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(fName, UriKind.Absolute) &&
               File.Exists(fName);
```

if the result is true, you can know for sure that the file format supplied by the user is valid and the file exists @ the file system.

Comment: it did work during the first load of my form.. but after i clicked next, then back to to that page again, the problem returned..

Comment: what are you getting as result?

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!File.Exists(filename))
{
// file does not exist or path is invalid
}
```